# Controlling dates with datepicker within razor application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, datepicker

I have an `asp.net mvc4` application in which I have this view

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            dayNamesMin: ["Di", "Lu", "Ma", "Me", "Je", "Ve", "Sa"],
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<br />
<br />

<h2 class="title">Ajouter une tâche à l'affaire  :  <label style="color:red">@affaire </label></h2>

<br />
<br />
<form action="/Planning/SaveTask" method="get">
    <table class="table_form">
        <tr>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="descr" value="" required/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Note</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="note" value="" required/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date de début</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="begin" value="" required/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date de fin</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="end" value="" required/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I'd like to ensure that the date `begin` be lower than the date `end` ie if `begin` date is 15th November , the `end`  date must be the 16th November or 17th November ......

Is there any way to do this by `javascript`?

Comment: `date begin be lower than the date end` this line is little confusing.  can you elaborate if possible add some example or SS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, you're trying *to restrict date between begin and end(I consider it as `from` and `to` dates)*

1) You can't have same class name, both should have different **`datepicker`** method.

2) In my consideration, I'm going with **`id`** 's called **`fromDate`** and **`toDate`**

```
$('#fromDate').datepicker({
    dayNamesMin: ["Di", "Lu", "Ma", "Me", "Je", "Ve", "Sa"],
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#toDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
$('#toDate').datepicker({
    dayNamesMin: ["Di", "Lu", "Ma", "Me", "Je", "Ve", "Sa"],
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#fromDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
```

When you close the `datepicker`, assign their `max` and `min` dates in opposite fashion that the trick!

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3MUyP/)

Hope you understood.